# Meaning behind version numbers (i.e. 0.1, 0.10.10, 1, etc)

Tags: functional-programming, logic, version

How are versions numbered? What is the proper idea behind going to next version, increments, etc?

For example, I often see v0.1, v0.2, v0.34567 etc. I assume these are softwares that are in beta, and haven't finished the first release yet.

But there are also many softwares that are v0.10.11, etc. how do they work?

Comment: Versions are numbered any way you like. There is no rule. There is a general practice that major, possibly incompatible, revisions have a new number before the decimal place, and minor, compatible, revisions have a new number after the decimal place, but there's nothing chiselled into stone tablets that requires it. It's up to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a specific standard - anybody can follow any scheme (or lack of scheme). It's up to corporate policy, development standards, or whatever guidelines you are under.

There are some popular standards out there. We try to follow the Semantic Versioning standard. The basic tenants include (quoted):

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

Links:

- Semantic Versioning: http://semver.org/
- Other versioning schemes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Schemes

Answer (score 1):

There are competing standards, which saddens me greatly, especially in a world where git is popular.

SymVer, as mentioned, helps a great deal, but a lot of popular software doesn't use it.

Unfortunately, this doesn't help a great deal when dealing with distros, who apply patches to specific versions of software, effectively changing it's version.

The closest to "proper" I have seen yet is done by NixOS. Each version of their software is hashed, as are all patches applied, and each end result has a different hash, line any change in Git.

The resulting output will be different as well, uniquely identifying it against others.

Until that method is adopted, it's a free-for-all, and versioning is not a consistent thing.